# No me cargan algunas paginas de mi web

Tags: php, xampp

Tengo el siguiente problema en mi pagina web, la misma ya esta terminada y cuando la hago funcionar desde mi servidor web o sea de forma local, anda perfecto. El problema es cuando subo toda la pagina web al servidor **ftp** para que la misma se pueda usar en el dominio **mipaginaweb.com.ar**, una vez esta subida al **ftp** entro a mi pagina y el `index` funciona normal, pero cuando me redirecciona a otras paginas que se encuentran dentro del mismo proyecto por ejemplo **mipaginaweb.com.ar/recordar.php** esta misma no me abre y así me pasa con algunas otras. 
El error que me da el navegador es el siguiente.

> Esta página no funciona La página xxxxxxxx.com.ar no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

En mi servidor uso `XAMPP` y programo con `PHP,HTML5, CSS` y `SQLServer`

**PD: Intentando acceder desde mi celular usando mi red de datos puedo acceder lo mas bien a las otras paginas que me tiran ese error, pensé que podía ser por problemas de cache en mi navegador pero borre el cache y sigue con el mismo problema.**

Comment: ¿Ya has intentado ingresar desde una pestaña de incógnito?

Comment: Hola @JonathanArias buen día, si ya intente de esa manera pero no hay caso.

Comment: En el localhost dices que funciona bien, con normalidad, ¿no?

Comment: Si podes entrar desde el celular a todas las paginas.. el problema es tu pc. probaste con otra pc?

Comment: @DaxTter77 Asi es, desde ahí todo ok

Comment: @gbianchi Si probe en otras pc's dentro de la misma red y nada

Comment: Y desde tu pc conectado a la red de tu celular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a todos por los comentarios.

Tenia problemas con mi Certificado SSL y después de instalarlo bien en el servidor y hacerle algunos ajustes mi pagina ya anda bien.